# PHPMailer Error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::isSTMP()

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send Mails using PHPMailer But its Showing me Error. This is test code. and When it's done I am thinking to add it to my main code. but  I don't know What's Wrong with this code. its just giving me this Error.

This is the Error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method 
PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::isSTMP() in

And Here is my Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

 $developmentMode = true;
 $mailer = new PHPMailer($developmentMode);

  try {
     $mailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mailer->isSMTP();            //edited here


 if ($developmentMode) {

   $mailer->SMTPOptions = [
    'ssl'=> [
         'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
      ]
   ];

 } 

 $mailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
 $mailer->Username = "mygmail@gmail.com";
 $mailer->Password = "password";
 $mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mailer->Port = 587;

$mailer-> setFrom("mygmail@gmail.com", "Izaya");
$mailer->addAddress("anothergmail@gmail.com","orihara");

  $mailer->isHTML(true);
   $mailer->Subject = "Hey There";
  $mailer->Body = "NICE TO MEET YOU IZAYA ";


   $mailer->send();
$mailer->ClearAllRecipients();
  echo "Mail has been Sent";



   }catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Email Error.INFO:" . $mailer->ErrorInfo;

  }


  ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You have a typo. It should be `isSMTP()`, not `isSTMP()`.

Comment: So now you should read the docs.

Comment: _Just a note:_ If  you set "verify_peer" to false and "allow_self_singed" to true, you just removed the protection of using SSL in the first place. You've just allowed "man-in-the-middle"-attacks. SSL is only secure if you're sure that the remote machine is who it says it is.If you don't verify it and allow self signed certificates, you will have no way of knowing.

Answer (score 1):

You just made a mistake in typing.Here is the error you are getting $mailer->isSTMP(); 
Change it to $mailer->isSMTP();

Answer (score 1):

**Use this code below with version more than v6.0**

```
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp1.example.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    // Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```